# How to order month abbreviation and year in SQL, format : MMMYYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I use the XML pivot to transpose the month columns as header and want to order it from the oldest month to current one, does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols  = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ QUOTENAME(period_month) FROM  updated_order_raw_data
         FOR XML Path(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

-- the purpose of temp-table is for summarize the total
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (
        order_id varchar(max),
        total_amount numeric
        )
INSERT INTO #temp_table

SELECT order_id, SUM(amount) as total_amount FROM updated_order_raw_data GROUP BY order_id

SET @query = 'SELECT * from 
             (
                SELECT a.order_id, report_name, period_month, amount, b.total_amount as difference
                FROM updated_order_raw_data a
                LEFT JOIN #temp_table b
                on a.order_id = b.order_id
                ) Src
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(amount)
                FOR period_month IN  (' + @cols + ')
            ) Piv 
            WHERE difference <> 0
            ORDER BY order_id, report_name '

EXECUTE(@query)
-- Drop temp-table
DROP TABLE #temp_table
```

Comment: Can you please send your query?

Comment: @TashilMoorateeah I added the code in the context.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the reminder and I will keep in mind.

Comment: You can do an order by when defining the @cols

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tashil Moorateeah,

I added order by here and it is workable.

```
SELECT @cols  = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ QUOTENAME(period_month) AS [period_month] FROM  updated_order_raw_data ORDER BY [period_month] 
         FOR XML Path(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```